# Full video background css height of video is extending beyond 100%;

Tags: html, css

video is not perfectly 100% it is extending beyond 100% ? I used absolute positioning but video's height is about 110% instead of 100%?

```
html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0; }

    section {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%; 
    }

    section video {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: video is not perfectly 100% it is extending beyond 100% ?

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
{ 
   width: auto; min-width: 100%; 
   height: auto; min-height: 100% 
}
```

That position absolute may also be creating a problem

Also have you tried

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Comment: yeah but I want full video on the screen. Using overflow it will delete the part going beyond the parent container.